# How to find other analytic solutions of an equation with a solution of ProductLog?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have an equation of the form

```
eq := 4/\[Pi] y x^2 - 1/16 c^2 Log[(2 x)/(\[Pi] w)] == cons
```

with the following set of parameters

```
parameters = {w -> 100, c -> 1, cons -> 0.46, y -> 0.5};
```

Replacing the parameters and solving the equation, gives

```
Solve[eq /. parameters, x]
```

$x = 0.114106, x = 0.351317$

But if I first solve the equation analytically and then replace the parameters, I get

```
 xans = x /. Solve[eq, x];
 xans /. parameters // Chop
```

$x=0.114106,x= -0.114106$

My question is that why the second answer appears in the first way, i.e., $x= 0.351317$ is missed in the 2nd way? How I can I find the analytic solution with this x as the answer?

Comment: Think of `xans = x /. Solve[eq, x, Reals] 
xans /. parameters` and compare with `xans = x /. Solve[eq, x]
xans /. parameters`.

Comment: `x==- 0.114106`  is not a solution in view of `4/\[Pi] y x^2 - 1/16 c^2 Log[(2 x)/(\[Pi] w)] - cons /. {w -> 100, 
  c -> 1, cons -> 0.46, y -> 0.5, x -> -0.114106}` which outputs `1.74124*10^-7 - 0.19635 I`. The `Solve` command uses nonequivalent transformations in some cases.

Comment: `Reduce[eq, x, Reals]` performs a warning "Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce." and returns the input. `Reduce[eq, x]` has no chance in view of four parameters.

Comment: @ user64494 Thanks for your comments. In fact I need the analytic solution which leads to  x=0.351317.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you solved it analytically by `Solve`, I think you got the warning message:

```
Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution
     information.
```

So it is not guaranteed that all the analytic solutions are obtained in this way. (Note that the [Lambert W function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) is multivalued.)
As user64494 pointed out, the second analytic solution leads to a wrong numerical answer in your case.

To get the second analytical solution, you need to select another branch for `ProductLog` (see also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182146/productlog-solution-is-not-full)):

```
x /. First[Solve[eq, x]] /. ProductLog[z_] -> ProductLog[-1, z] /. parameters  (* 0.351317 + 0. I *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help.